# change all html code

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use JQuery AJAX. I need to send some data to page, than receive data, remove all tag (include html), and set new page like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Example</body>
</head>
```

I use this JQuery script:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "name=John",
  success: function(msg){
    //how remove and set new page?
  }
 });
```

Comment: Why not simply redirect to the new page?

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea compared to a normal postback, which does just about the same thing.

Comment: Pardon me, but what sense does this make if you want to remove as much as html tag? What difference does this make from simply loading a new page?

Comment: If you need to overwrite the entire page, you should simply use `window.location = url`.

Comment: you can use jQuery('body').html(<your ajax response>)

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura This is bad advice. You should never be replacing the body with new content returned from ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "name=John",
  success: function(msg){
    window.location = 'your/new/page/url';
  }
 });
```